# Rails 3 link_to rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, link-to, rake-task

I've created a rake task in my application and now I want the task to be accesible for app users from a link on a menu, but I don't know how to invoke it from there. Something like this...?

```
<%= link_to t('backup'), Rake::Task['backup'].invoke %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it. Link_to can link to something static or controller action. So you need to create some action, where you can invoke your Rake Task.

```
class MyTasksController < ApplicationController 
  def rake_it
    Rake::Task['backup'].invoke
  end
end

<%= link_to  t("backup"), {:controller => :my_tasks, :action => "rake_it"} %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried as you said, but the next error appears:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant MyTasksController::Rake)
```

Edit answer:

I finally could do it by this way:

```
class MyTasksController < ApplicationController
  def rake_it
    system ('rake backup:db:mysql')
    redirect_to :action => 'index', :controller => '/events'
  end
end
```

Comment: you might need to shove an 'include Rake' in your controller?