# rails 3 rake task link

Tags: rake, link-to

I tried to link a rake task from a menu but I couldn't, as I explained in the question [Rails 3 link_to rake task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028517/rails-3-link-to-rake-task)

but It doesn't work for me. That produces  the error uninitialized constant MyTasksController::Rake

any idea?

thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 1):

I finally could do it by this way:

```
class MyTasksController < ApplicationController
  def rake_it
    system ('rake backup:db:mysql')
    redirect_to :action => 'index', :controller => '/events'
  end
end
```